# MD5 Comparison with Usercake and PHP121 Messenger

Tags: php, encryption, hash, md5, usercake

I am trying to incorporate the [Php121 Messenger](http://www.php121.com/) into an existing website. The website uses usercake accounts.

It does not recognize password because the type of md5 encryption for the password.

Usercake uses this type of encryption

```
function generateHash($plainText, $salt = null)
{
if ($salt === null)
{
    $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 25);
}
else
{
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 25);
}

return $salt . sha1($salt . $plainText);
}
```

This is the function from php121 messenger for authenticating user. I have all the database settings correct and it finds the user name but password doesn't match because of the hash format

```
function userLookup($username, $password) {
global $php121db, $password;
global $db_usertable, $dbf_uid, $dbf_uname, $dbf_upassword, $dbf_passwordtype, $dbf_uemail;
global $dbf_user_chatting, $dbf_smilies, $dbf_level, $dbf_showrequest;
global $dbf_upassword_len;

    $stop = "";
    if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT $dbf_uname FROM $db_usertable WHERE $dbf_uname='$username'",$php121db)) == 0) $stop .= _USERNAME_NOT_FOUND . "<br>";
    if ($stop == ""){
            $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT $dbf_upassword from $db_usertable WHERE $dbf_uname='$username'", $php121db));
    if ($dbf_passwordtype == "md5") {
        if ($row[0] != substr(md5($password), 0, $dbf_upassword_len)) $stop .= _INCORRECT_PASSWORD . "<br>";
    } else if ($dbf_passwordtype == "plaintext") {
        if ($row[0] != substr($password, 0, $dbf_upassword_len)) $stop .= _INCORRECT_PASSWORD . "<br>";
    }
    else if ($dbf_passwordtype == "salted") { 
if ($row[0] != substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 25)) $stop .= _INCORRECT_PASSWORD . "<br>"; 

 }
}
return($stop);
}
```

I need to figure out how to compare the md5 hash

http://forums.php121.com/viewtopic.php?t=1162

Tried to use something like this which is used for joomla but no luck.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The userLookup is simply taking a 25-character substring of some random unique id. substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 25)) seems to be a random session id. The upper function uses it to generate a salt that is both appended to the SHA-1 and appended with the real password in SHA-1. The salted mode in the userLookup() function does not match the process used in the generateHash() function and therefore the passwords will never match in the database.

Comment: What should the salted mode be then?